# Hot to make element in the center if I don't use justify-content?

Tags: html, css, html-email

My HTML file is for `html email`, so I can't use `justify-content`.

Here is the original code for center:

```
<div style="display: flex; justify-content: center;">
  <p>Hello &nbsp</p>
  <p>World</p>
</div>
```

For `html email` I have to give up use `justify-content`, change to use `text-align: center`

```
<div style="display: flex; text-align: center;">
  <p>Hello &nbsp</p>
  <p>World</p>
</div>
```

but in the result element is on the left side not in the center, if I have to use `display: flex`

How to achieve it for `html email` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why use flex then? Try this:

```
<div style="text-align:center;">
  <p style="display:inline-block;">Hello &nbsp</p>
  <p style="display:inline-block;">World</p>
</div>
```

Comment: display:inline-block; is working  Thanks !

Comment: Wouldn't it be inline-block for the div (and a width), and text-align for the paragraph?